# How can I create in C# a page to response to another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, response

How can I create in C# a page to response to another one? So when you press the button,login form opens in a new widow(browser tab or widow), and as you login... the form automaticaly refresh the first page.

Like the Open ID form. You press the (Connect with Facebook) button it opens a new window with the login form and then it refreshes the the website where u pressed the button.

Sorry for my English!! :) & please help!

Comment: It's javascript related, you can refresh a page only through javascript/user interaction

Comment: So can you give an advise, an link, or an example so i have were to learn from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open a new window from a button click like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:button type="button" id="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('newPage.aspx'); OnClick="ServerSideCode" />
```

Or with a regular HTML button:

```
 <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Click me" onclick="javascript:window.open('newPage.aspx');" />
```

On `newPage.aspx` you define a function to auto close the current form and reload the parent form. Something like:

```
function closeMe()
{
   window.parent.location.reload();
   self.close();
}
```

And on server-side, when you handle your button Click event, you add this line all the way at the bottom depending on whether the process was successful. Example:

```
if(loginSuccessful)
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "whatever", "closeMe();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about AJAX. And technically, a C# code deal with pages (it may however handle HTTP requests & replies).

Answer (score 0):

you can use  ( if you open a new window) the `opener` object.

and you can also make use of the `PostBackUrl`

also you can make use of  `form1.Action`